# Why won't my linked list add nodes? (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to add a new Node to the end of my linked list but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. It adds the first element because it's a special case but then ignores all of the other assignments when I step through the debugging.

Here's the test I'm running:

```
@Test
public void testInsertElement()
{
PriorityList<String> list = new LinkedPriorityList<String>();
list.insertElementAt(0, "first");
list.insertElementAt(1, "second");
list.insertElementAt(2, "third");
assertEquals("first" , list.getElementAt(0));
assertEquals("second", list.getElementAt(1));
assertEquals("third" , list.getElementAt(2));
}
```

It fails on the second assertion because nothing is added after the first.

Here's the constructor for the Node Objects:

```
public class LinkedPriorityList<E> implements PriorityList<E> {

  private class Node
  {

    private E data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(E element)
    {
      data = element;
      next = null;
    }
  }
```

And finally the code that is failing on me:

```
public void insertElementAt(int index, E element) throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
      if(index>size() || index<0) //can only be between 0 and size()
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

      if(size()==0)
          first = new Node(element); //adding the first element. This works
      else
      {
          if(index == size()) //if an element is being added to the end
          {
              Node ref = first;                //assigning ref to the first element of the list
              for(;ref!=null; ref = ref.next); //stepping through the list until ref is null
              ref = new Node(element);         //assigning the null reference a new Node. Doesn't assign
          }
          else //if an element is being inserted in the list. untested...
          {
              Node ref = first;
              Node temp = new Node(element);
              for(int i=1; i<index; i++)
                  ref = ref.next;
              temp = ref.next;
              ref = temp;
          }
      }
      size++; //keeping track of how many elements in list
  }
```

I think this works but if you want the get method too, here it is:

```
public E getElementAt(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
    if(index>=size() || index<0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    Node ref = first;
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
        ref = ref.next;
    return ref.data;
  }
```

Comment: If the size isn't 0, then your insertElementAt method does nothing useful. It ends up assigning a value to a *local* variable, but that's all. It never adds a new element into the list. Which statement did you *expect* to do that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include it. First is actually a global instance variable

Answer (score 3):

When `index == size`, you want to create a new node, find the last node in the list, and assign the new node to its `next` pointer.

The last node is the one whose `next` pointer is null.

This should be enough to let you implement the algorithm by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `temp` node when adding at the end too (to keep track of the last element)

```
if (index == size())
{
    Node ref = first, temp = first;
    for (; ref != null; temp = ref, ref = ref.next);
    temp.next = new Node(element);    
}
```

By just assigning the new `Node` to `ref`; it doesn't link it to the current last node's `next`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you meant to do:

```
for(; ref.next != null; ref = ref.next) {
  /* intentionally empty */
}
ref.next = new Node(element);
```

Note that I'm both testing and assigning `ref.next`, not `ref` itself.

Comment: Am I the only one to find that a while loop would be much more readable here, and wouldn't need any comment?

Comment: @JBNizet That and extracting it into a method, i.e. `getLastNode()`.

Comment: I agree, but I tried to keep the changes to his code minimal, so he finds easily *where* this part is supposed to go to.